# String to DateTime SQL Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

I know this has been asked several times but I haven't seen it asked for my particular situation.

> If a text was in this format: **Dec 30 2006 12:38AM** Is there any way to
>   convert this to an actual datetime. I am not excited about creating a function to parse this to a date using substrings, etc.

A previous developer developed the whole application and decided to store all the date values in the database as a VARCHAR which conveniently changed them from something like: `2016-12-30 00:38:00`
to `Dec 30 2006 12:38AM`. This makes them non comareable (SMH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `cast()`:

```
select cast('Dec 30 2006 12:38AM' as datetime)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/11698) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: perfect. Not sure why it never worked for me the 1st time

Comment: @logixologist Possibly because it's not language safe. Try `set language french;` first, for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I'm amazed by how versatile `cast()`/`convert()` are when converting to dates.  They understand all sorts of formats that are not otherwise easily parsable

Comment: could you please help me with similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037209/datetime-conversion-from-mongodb-string-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

--Please try this

declare @var varchar(30) = 'Dec 30 2006 12:38AM'
select convert(datetime, @var)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are converting strings (which is always risky), I would suggest try_convert() if 2012+.  Try_Convert() will return a null if the conversion fails rather than throwing an error.

**Example**

```
Select ValidDate = try_convert(datetime,'Dec 30 2006 12:38AM')
      ,BogusDate = try_convert(datetime,'Not a Valid Date String')
```

Returns

```
ValidDate                BogusDate
2006-12-30 00:38:00.000  NULL
```